# How does Windows 7 restore take up disk space?

Tags: windows-7, restore

I noticed my C drive getting low a month ago and then boom it went from 20GB to nothing in a couple days.  And every time I deleted something... boom back to zero...

I figured out that system restore was causing the issue.

So then I mess with the restore settings.  I tell it to save less and to put the restore on a connected USB.  First this did not work right.  I asked it to save My Videos folder and then it saves a bunch of videos on another drive...

Then I notice that even we creating restore point to another drive that it was taking up space on my C:.  So now there isn't enough space to create these "helper" files so it runs out of space during every restore try.  I delete files and it tries again and can't make it.  Rinse and repeat.

So how do I get rid of all of the restore helper files?  I have 150GB hard drive and can only account for 90-100GB.

Comment: http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/07/where-did-all-my-hard-drive-space-go/

Comment: I assume using a larger HDD isn't an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it can take up space, that seems a little too much and I am thinking something else may be going on.

Try to run windirstat - http://windirstat.info/download.html and see if you can see where your space is going.

Comment: Thanks William.  It was my restore hitting my inetpub folder trying to copy files that I have special perms on and then writing over and over to the log files.  Holy cow 60GB of log files.  Didn't even think to check because it is a dev machine that usually has 1MB of log files a year.

Comment: Also why the **** would the W7 restore hit my inetpub files?  I have only selected my user's docs and videos.  Can't stand this functionality.

Comment: @DavidMoore No predicting Windows recently it seems! But this does seem weird... any junction folders or similar that may have some sort of recursion back to the inetpub folder? You have me curious now!

Comment: no.   I used to clean computers for extra cash in college and this one totally has me stumped.  Never dug into the W7 restore functionality because I have my own backup of files to a content server... but once I played around with it after issue - it sucks.  I check marked to save my docs, videos, music folders.  Well if My Music is checkmarked it tried to backup my "Music" folder which is 400GB and on another drive - it is local.  So I am guessing it tried to backup inetpub stuff because My Documents was checked.  Some stuff can't be copied (my setting) so big logs!